# Steering in top-down racer with Libgdx

Tags: libgdx, steering-behaviors

I'm a beginner in game development and as a little project I thought I should try to do a top-down racer game much like the good old Slicks n Slide.

I've seen several tutorials and questions about steering and car physics but most is more complicated than what I need and uses box2d with wheels turning and so on.

I want it to keep simple and only want three buttons. Accelerate, turn left and turn right.
And my "car" is for now just a circle :-)

My question is how to do the steering. If someone can explain it simple to me I would be very thankful.
I know I need to use sin and cos to get the steering angle but I haven't figured out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a very minimalistic car you won't need anything other than two values: `velocity` and `direction`. Both values can be just a floating point number.

When steering left/right, adjust the `direction`, which could be as simple as being the angle the car is facing. Accelerating or breaking will modify the `velocity`.

```
if (key_left)
    direction -= 0.001;
else if (key_right)
    direction += 0.001;

if (key_up)
    velocity += 0.001;
else if (key_down)
    velocity -= 0.001;
```

To move the car, you'd use simple trigonometry:

```
pos.x += velocity * cos(direction);
pos.y += velocity * sin(direction);
```

Of course you can modify this further, e.g. only adjusting `direction` based on `velocity` (so you can't turn while standing still). In addition, you'll most likely want to add some friction as well:

```
velocity *= 0.99;
```